# What elements of the field extension are fixed by the subgroup $\mathbb Z_3$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

In [this excellent lecture by Matthew Salomone](https://youtu.be/P8__4fzMmsM), discussing the correspondence between subgroups and subfields for the polynomial $x^3 - 2$ the following statement is made, which I don't quite get:

> [Re: subgroup $\mathbb Z_3=\{e,r,r^2\}$] ... because we are rotating around the $2^{1/3}\text{'s}$ we are leaving the $\zeta_3\text{'s}$ (the cube roots of unity) in place.

Here is the picture on the screen at the time of the statement (above), as well as at the completion of the lattice (below):

[image]

Here is the entire diagram with some corrections (clarified in [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3744682/152225)):

[image]

My intuition says that the cyclic group permutes the roots of unity, and leaves $\sqrt[3]2$ fixed.

---

Here's what I learned from the now accepted answer:

The dihedral group $D_3$ leaves the cube roots of unity unchanged with pure rotations, yet they swap when flipping the triangle:

[image]

The combined actions of rotation and flipping are better understood with the Cayley diagram in the upper-left hand corner of the image below:

[image]

Comment: Which cyclic group? That of order $3$ fixes the cube roots of unity and permutes the three cube roots of $2$ cyclically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we know that the automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega_3)$, which fix $\mathbb{Q}$ are determined by the action on $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega_3$, where $\omega_3$ is a third root of unity. It's trivial to conclude that such an automorphism sends $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to a root of $x^3 - 2$ and $\omega_3$ to a root of $x^2 + x + 1$. Making all possible combinations we get:

$$ i :
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sqrt[3]{2} \to \sqrt[3]{2}\\
       \omega_3 \to \omega_3
     \end{array}
\quad \quad  \tau:
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sqrt[3]{2} \to \omega_3\sqrt[3]{2}\\
       \omega_3 \to \omega_3
     \end{array}
\quad \quad   \tau^2:
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sqrt[3]{2} \to \omega_3^2\sqrt[3]{2}\\
       \omega_3 \to \omega_3
     \end{array}
$$
$$ \sigma :
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sqrt[3]{2} \to \sqrt[3]{2}\\
       \omega_3 \to \omega_3^2
     \end{array}
\quad \quad  \sigma\tau:
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sqrt[3]{2} \to \omega_3^2\sqrt[3]{2}\\
       \omega_3 \to \omega_3^2
     \end{array}
\quad \quad  \sigma\tau^2:
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sqrt[3]{2} \to \omega_3\sqrt[3]{2}\\
       \omega_3 \to \omega_3^2
     \end{array}
$$

Now $G = S_3 = D_3$ and the unique cyclic group is $\{i, \tau, \tau^2\}$. Now in the basis $\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4},\omega_3,\omega_3\sqrt[3]{2},\omega_3\sqrt[3]{4}\}$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega_3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ the only fixed elements are $1, \omega_3$, which obvioulsy corresponds to the field $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_3)$

Now by checking which elements of the basis remain fixed by a subgroup of $G$, you can determine the corresponding fixed fields.

---

Although it might not be the right way to think about you can think of a triangle, whose vertices are labeled with the roots of $x^3−2$, the front side labeled with $\omega_3$, while the back with $\omega^2_3$. Obviously the rotations, keep the back and front side the same. Anyway I would prefere explicitly writing the automorphisms, as I did and computing the fixed fields by the subgroups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I am hitting a misunderstanding: The way  I look at it (most likely incorrectly) is that $\tau$ would send $1$ to $\omega_3$; while $\tau^2$ would send $\omega_3 \mapsto \omega_3^2$; and $\tau^2$ would map $\omega_3^2 \mapsto 1.$ In other words $\tau$ would make the roots of unity spin around, while it would be the role of $\sigma$ to act on $\sqrt[3]2.$ What am I missing?

Comment: @mathkoan Any automorphism of $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega_3)$ fixes the base field, i.e $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore we always have $1 \to 1$ for any automorphism. On the other side although technically $1$ is a root of unity, automorpishm don't just switch roots of unity. In fact we have that the minimal polynomial of $\omega_3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^2+x+1$, so in fact any automorphism permutes the roots of it, i.e. $\omega_3, \omega_3^2$.

Comment: @mathkoan Indeed any automorpishm that permutes $\omega_3$ and $\omega_3^2$ must have even order, so it can't be included in isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ in $G$, so for sure we know that that subgroup fixes at least the field $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_3)$.

Comment: I guess I'm asking for some help in understanding the symmetries implied in the actions $\tau,\tau^2,\sigma, \sigma\tau, \sigma\tau^2$ (rotations and flips) vis-a-vis the dihedral group $D_3$, and not understanding how the rotations leave the roots of unity (which are essentially rotations in the complex plane) unaltered. What is the meaning of flipping in this case, as compared to an equilateral triangle?

Comment: @mathkoan I'm not sure this is a good explanation, but you can think of a triangle, whose vertices are labeled with the roots of $x^3 - 2$, the front side is labeled with $\omega_3$, while the back with $\omega_3^2$. Obviously the rotations, keep the back and front side the same. Anyway I would prefere explicitly writing the automorphisms, as I did and computing the fixed fields by the subgroups.

Comment: Great! I'll approve your answer no matter what, but I'd very much appreciate it if you could include this comment on your answer in some way. It is **the** answer I needed to see it.

Comment: @mathkoan I don't think it makes a lot of difference, but if you insist I can add my comment in the answer.

Comment: One final detail: You mean "whose vertices are labeled with the **real** roots of $x^3-2,$ correct?

Comment: @mathkoan No, in fact $x^3 - 2$ has a single real root.

Comment: Got you! My bad...So the vertices would be $\sqrt[3]2, \; \omega_3\sqrt[3]2,\; \omega_3^2\sqrt[3]2,$ correct?